# How do I get non-matching lines without using awk or sed?

Tags: bash

Can I get a non-matching line *without* using `awk` or `sed`

I am not using `awk` or `sed` because the text files I'm using do not have constant number of columns and their arrangement changes. For example, I have this text file called `error1.txt` which contains a lot of lines like this:

```
>304    00000800020030000000000032000AC00000000032000AC00000000000000000000000000000000022000000000    00000    \Device\Termdd      en-US       Classic                                          Error Description 1.               System  MAN-RW-ADC1.PH.NIIT.com     50          
>50 49162   49162   18256   18256                   0x80000000000000        2   2                   TermDD      0       11/10/2013    11:47
```

If I want to get the lines:

```
Error Description 1
11/10/2013
11:47
```

the only thing I have right now is:

```
`egrep '(Error.*Description.*1)' /home/xxxxxx/Documents/error1.txt`
```

What command should I use to invert matches without `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: You want to get only lines matching that pattern? You want to get only lines that don't match that pattern? Something else?

Comment: I want to get the lines 'Error Description 1 11/10/2013 11:47'

Comment: That's not a line on its own. That's part of a line. You want to get the entire line with that content on it?

Comment: I see an entire line that starts with `000008000... \Device\Termdd... Error Description 1...`. Do you mean the segment that only contains `Error Description ...` or the entire line itself?

Comment: Funny that you tagged the question both `sed` and `awk` but explicitly ask for a way to do it without them.

Comment: Sounds like you want `grep`.

Comment: there, i removed the tags. Sorry, I am still trying to learn the ropes of Stackoverflow and for technicality's sake, I want to get Error Description 1 11/10/2013 11:47, PART of the line.

Comment: "text files I'm using do not have constant number of columns and their arrangement changes."  You really need to define the format better or at least provide more than one line as an example.

Comment: you needn't always count from left to right, with awk ,you can count from right to left by $NF, $NF-1, with that, may easily fix your issue.

Comment: I think some of the answers are tripping up because of the formatting of your input file.  I've edited the question to make it clearer your input file only has one line.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed

```
sed -r 's/.*(Error Description [0-9]*).*([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})$/\1 \2/' error1.txt

Error Description 1 11/10/2013 11:47
```

grep with `-P`

```
grep -iPo "Error.*Description.*1.*\K[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$" error1.txt

11/10/2013 11:47
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -o` will give you a portion of a result string, so

```
cat<<EOF |
304 00000800020030000000000032000AC00000000032000AC00000000000000000000000000000000022000000000 00000 \Device\Termdd en-US Classic Error Description 1. System MAN-RW-ADC1.PH.NIIT.com 50 >50 49162 49162 18256 18256 0x80000000000000 2 2 TermDD 0 11/10/2013 11:47
EOF
grep -o 'Error Description [0-9]*'
```

will yield `Error Description 1`. The problem is that it will not also get the timestamp on the same line, without also grabbing all the rest of the garbage in-between. If you want to store the results on two separate lines (once for `Error Description` and once for the timestamp), you could save each line into a variable and `grep` it.

Otherwise, `sed` and `awk` would give the most concise results, since it will let you use positional replacements.

Is there a particular reason you cannot use those two?

Comment: I can't use awk or sed because the text files i'm planning to use do not have the same number of columns and has no constant pattern.

Comment: sed does not need columns, you can do something like sed 's/.*\(Error Description [0-9]*\).*[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4}\ [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$/\1\ \2/' (very untested, assumes all of the above is a single line..)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) regular expressions:

```
$ re="(Error Description [[:digit:]]*).*([[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{4}[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2})"
$ while IFS='' read -r ln; do [[ $ln =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2}"; done < error1.txt 
Error Description 1 11/10/2013    11:47
$
```